# Unable to use (and even to list) pure attributes tables (with no geometry in them). I need to do a flow using one containing {from, to} cities codes

Tags: qgis, attribute-table

I have to do a flow of home-work trips.

### The base of my work is a geographical layer of cities

an *OpenStreetMap* map of French cities that has their shapes and cities codes (named : `INSEE`) :

[image: The base geographical layer : French cities]

### The second source, an attribute table with the list of the trips

it's a normal SGBD table named `deplacement_domicile_travail_2017` that has no geometry.
This table tells from what and to what cities are the trips, and will be used to ask *QGIS* to draw the arrows between them.

[image: Attribute table with flow data : city codes (start, end)]

### But tables with no geometry are not listed anywhere under QGIS

However, I see no way under *QGIS 3.14* to perform my flow layer.

1. In explorer, *PostGIS* folder doesn't list me the `deplacement_domicile_travail_2017`, and in fact, no other non-geographical table (even if they have a primary key).
2. If I edit my layer and go the *Joins* menu, only geometrical tables or view are offered for targets, and not pure attributes tables.
3. If I was to create a view on `deplacement_domicile_travail_2017` in order to add geometry on it (and join it would have to link it to my OSM table), this view would have two geometries on it : one for the starting city, one for the destination city. It would cause other troubles and I want to avoid that.

[image: PostGIS don't list attribute table]

### Question :

How are used pure attributes tables, those containing only data columns and no geometry, on *QGIS* ?

Answer (score 4):

Right-click the database connection - Edit Connection - check "Also list tables with no geometry":

[image]

Comment: Oh... How tricky it is ! I would have figured to search for such option. I'm lucky that you know it ! I'll try it in a few hours,

Comment: Few hours have passed since ... so if the solution solved your problem, consider accepting it by hitting the checkmark next to it.